# A property of pseudo-inverse function

Tags: real-analysis

Let the pseudo-inverse of the non-decreasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $$f^{-1}(y)=\inf\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x)\geq y\}$$
I would like to prove that for real $x=f^{-1}(y)$ and for any $\varepsilon>0$ $$f(x-\varepsilon)<y\leq f(x+\varepsilon)$$
The right inequality is clear to me but I can't see why would the left inequality have to be strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x - \epsilon) \ge y$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  Then,
$$
x - \epsilon \in \left\{ x \in \Bbb{R} : f(x) \ge y \right\},
$$
and so $f^{-1}(y) \le x - \epsilon$.  This contradicts the definition of $x = f^{-1}(y)$ since it implies that
$$
x \le x - \epsilon.
$$